# Some fonts come up as fractions in applications

Tags: fonts, skype, ubuntu-font-family

My skype has long since been using a fraction font to display caller names. This looked funny but didn't bother me since I knew who I was calling. However Now I am trying to login with the Everpad application and the boxes will not allow me to type the correct characters.

- I do use ibus for Chinese character input.
- I looked through my fonts and didn't see one that makes letters into fractions, I used both the writer and fontviewer to go through all the fonts.

[image: Evernote, cannot login because fonts look like fractions]

[image: Skype calls always show the name in fractions/]

How should I adjust my font?

Comment: Which IM engine are you using to type Chinese?

Comment: I'm sorry I don't understand your question, but I use the "Intelligent pinyin" as the Chinese input source.

Comment: That's what I meant. I think the most commonly used engine for Simplified Chinese in Ubuntu is _ibus-sunpinyin_. Maybe worth a try.